# What aspects of Thunderbirds (2004) did Gerry Anderson dislike?

Tags: thunderbirds, gerry-anderson

Looking at the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbirds_%28film%29) it is made clear that Mr Anderson (RIP) did not approve of *Thunderbirds* (2004):

> "It was disgraceful that such a huge amount of money was spent with people who had no idea what Thunderbirds was about and what made it tick."
>
> He also said that it was "the biggest load of crap I have ever seen in my entire life."

Now as a dedicated Thunderbirds fan myself I quite enjoyed the film and thought it was reasonably accurate (although there were certain aspects that the writers took some creative license with such as the creation of Fermat or a wife for Kyrano).  Sylvia Anderson also was reasonably pleased with the film (see the Wikipedia article).

My question is **what aspects of the film did Mr Anderson (RIP) not approve of?**  I'm looking for quotes that actually explain this.

Comment: http://youtu.be/ek4tpoFgGP4?t=4m37s

Comment: My view was that he felt that because the film flopped, it hurt his chances of ever making another TV series. Also, he signed the rights over years ago which means that he didn't earn a penny from the film...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, for starters he [absolutely hated](http://www.bbc.co.uk/berkshire/features/2004/07/gerry_anderson_iview.shtml) Lady Penelope's new car;

> I've had nothing to do with the show, except a couple of months ago,
>   they suddenly realised that my name is synonymous with Thunderbirds.
>   They offered me (wait for it!) $750,000 to sign my name and say how
>   good the picture was. I hadn't seen it at that point so they said
>   they'd email me a picture of [Lady Penelope's Ford](http://img.thesun.co.uk/aidemitlum/archive/00084/F_200405_may14ed_img_84699a.jpg). It came and I
>   thought it was an absolute monstrosity. I thought that was an
>   indication of what the film was going to be like, and I turned it
>   down.

And he was less than impressed about the fact that he was totally excluded from the production :

> As I sat down, Tim Bevan looked at his watch and said "lovely to meet
>   you Gerry, but I've got an appointment". He rushed off and left me
>   with his producer and then-director, Peter Hewitt. We talked about the
>   possibility of me being a consultant - I wouldn't have minded that.
>   But now that I've seen the end product I'm very glad that I didn't.
>   Three days later I got a letter saying that they'd got enough creative
>   people on board and they didn't need my services. If anybody tried to
>   insult me, they really succeeded.